# why does split coerce double to integer in R and is there a workaround

Tags: r, split, type-conversion

One can build dates in R from numeric types, even fractional values. It's not very common, but it happens for instance when averaging dates. Unfortunately, they seem to break `split`

```
> as.Date(-1, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "1969-12-31"
> as.Date(-1.0001, origin = "1970-01-01")
[1] "1969-12-30"
> split(as.Date(-1, origin = "1970-01-01"), 1)[[1]]
[1] "1969-12-31"
> split(as.Date(-1.0001, origin = "1970-01-01"), 1)[[1]]
[1] "1969-12-31" #this is wrong
> unclass(split(as.Date(-1, origin = "1970-01-01"), 1)[[1]])
[1] -1
> unclass(split(as.Date(-1.0001, origin = "1970-01-01"), 1)[[1]])
[1] -1 #this is "why"
```

So two dates that were different are made equal by a `split`. Do people agree that this is a bug or am I missing the deep reason? Any workarounds? Thanks

Comment: Strawman workaround: `lapply(split(as.character(dates), index), as.Date)`. Preserves the date but changes the underlying representation. Needs an `lapply`, slow in certain cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For whatever reason, `split.Date` coerces the `Date` input to integer:

```
> split.Date
function (x, f, drop = FALSE, ...) 
{
    y <- split.default(as.integer(x), f, drop = drop)
    for (i in seq_along(y)) class(y[[i]]) <- "Date"
    y
}
<bytecode: 0x2effb98>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

This is at minimum an infelicity between the function and the documentation, since `?Date` says, "the date should be an integer, but this is not enforced in the internal representation.". Some might consider it a bug. I'm not sure.

You can avoid that by calling `split.default` directly.

```
> split.default(as.Date(-1.0001, origin = "1970-01-01"), 1)[[1]]
[1] "1969-12-30"
```

Comment: No way!! It seems the only goal of writing this method was to introduce this bug. The default works just fine. Thanks

Comment: @piccolbo `svn annotate src/library/base/R/dates.R` lead me to https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-July/050134.html with the motivation for introduction being performance (still substantial for vectors of >1e6 elements). Though obviously correct is more important.

Comment: thanks @MartinMorgan, that spared more pain. It seems that all of the time is spent by split.default in the for loop assignment, line before the last. Not sure why it's so slow. Compromise could be replacing as.integer with as.numeric, but that would make the use of double Dates more common, and as you said that's iffy at best. Better compromise could be x = if(is.double(x)) x else as.integer(x). Given my record of bug reporting, I will leave it to others to submit this.

Comment: @piccolbo this will be fixed in the next release of R (basically, unclass() rather than as.integer())